# Why does my hyperlink not scroll to the appropriate in Edge?

Tags: scroll, hyperlink, microsoft-edge

Please open Microsoft Edge and go to this site here: https://www.bodecanada.com/

Click on the Scroll button at the bottom of the blue box at the top of the page. Notice that it doesn't scroll further down the page. If it does, try it a few times. It will eventually stop working. This bug is only replicable in Edge.

We developed this site in Vue.js. This is the code for the scroll button:

```
          <div id="scroll-wrap">
            <a @click="$vuetify.goTo('#section2')" class="white--text" style="margin:0 auto;">
              <p class="white--text" style="font-size:12px;">Scroll</p>
              <v-icon color="white" style="width:100%; text align:center;">expand_more</v-icon>
            </a>
          </div>
```

Can anyone tell why it won't always scroll in Edge? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could directly use `<a>` tag [`href` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) link to an element with a specified id within the page.

```
<a href="#section2" @click="$vuetify.goTo('#section2')" class="white--text" style="margin:0 auto;">
```